# Parallel.ForEach and SQL insert in batches of 20

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, thread-safety, parallel.foreach

I am writing some code inside a `Parallel.ForEach` statement. Each thread is supposed to do some work, then insert the result in a List. When the list hits a count of %20, it should insert the items into the DB, as I don't want each thread to open a new connection and insert one item.
Obviously, with the below code, many threads are modifying my list and it is erroring with
`Collection was modified`. I also can't use `Lock` as I lose the benefit of parallelization if every thread has to wait for the lock to modify the list.

What would be the best way to achieve the above? I tried pausing the Foreach and then resuming but was not successful.

```
private ItemsDAL _itemsDal = new ItemsDAL();
public void Run()
{
    List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1500; i++)
    {
        items.Add(new Item()
        {
            Details = "Test " + i
        });
    }

    Parallel.ForEach(items, (oneItem) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Adding item with Details " + oneItem.Details);
        _itemsDal.InsertToDatabase(oneItem);
    });

}
```

DAL Class

```
public class ItemsDAL
{
    object _lock = new object();
    private List<Item> _itemsToInsert = new List<Item>();

    public void InsertToDatabase(Item item)
    {
        _itemsToInsert.Add(item);
        if (_itemsToInsert.Count >= 20)
        {

            //Add to database in bulk (Blocs of 20)
            using (ForeachContext db = new ForeachContext())
            {
                foreach (var itemToInsert in _itemsToInsert)
                {
                    db.Items.Add(itemToInsert);
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            _itemsToInsert.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps using a thread-safe collection might help, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=net-7.0

Comment: you can also use semaphores and critical section, to manage inserting into the list, so that only one thread can write at a time

Comment: I can easily use a Lock, and that guarantees that only one thread inserts into the list, but that way, I will have threads waiting for the lock to insert into the list, and that means I'd lose the benefit of Parallel.Foreach. I tested this, and the execution time of it compared to a regular foreach is the same.

Comment: `I don't want each thread to open a new connection and insert one item` - that is why [connection pooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling) is enabled by default.

Comment: parallelisation need other concepts a list can't be parallelized , but a array of lists where every thread has it own

Comment: Use a 20 size semaphore and when you acquire and fill it up to 20, send the list to the processing thread, exchange the list with new one and release all the semaphores

Comment: Have you tried using a simple `foreach` instead of `Parallel.ForEach`? How does this compare to calling `SaveChanges` for one item at a time? My guess is that you are trying to parallelize something that might not be parallelizable.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I did, and the difference is significant. The issue is that there is a lot of work during the ForEach before inserting into the DB. I am calling a function that is making API calls. In the code example, the process is only printing out a string, but in real life, the process is quite long, which is why I need it to run in parallel.

Comment: If most of the work is in worker, then list synchronization should be the least problem for you

Comment: @siggemannen What do you mean? It's all related. Ideally, I can pause all threads when my list hits a count of 20, and then add the items to the DB, then resume the threads and so on. Let's pretend the "Console.WriteLine("Adding item with Details " + oneItem.Details);" was a "Thread.Sleep(2*60*1000)", what would be the solution here? I am looking into your Semaphore of 20 as that could be a promising solution.

Comment: You could edit the question and add something like `Thread.Sleep(1000); // Simulate an API call`, to give us a more accurate representation of your actual problem. But I am interested to know if the batching idea by itself provides any performance benefits, or it's just a needless complication. Is it really faster to call `SaveChanges` for 20 records at a time, instead of doing it one by one?

Comment: I mean let's say your main operation takes 2 seconds. The difference between using synchronized list and unsynchronized list is of a couple of magnitudes lower that this time, so it shouldn't hurt to use a synchronized list version. But I'd you have millions of list operations then it might make larger difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I also can't use Lock as I lose the benefit of parallelization if every thread has to wait for the lock to modify the list.

Not really.  Adding an item to the list is *very fast*.  And locking for just that operation you're not going to loose any benefit of parallelization for the part where the threads "do some work" before inserting into the list.

Really, you can simply use a `lock(_lock) {...}` block for the whole body of `InsertToDatabase`.  And that will

> pause all threads when my list hits a count of 20, and then add the
> items to the DB

The case where the list has less than 20 items, the lock lasts only for the duration of

```
_itemsToInsert.Add(item);
```

which in the context of a method that makes API calls or writes to a database is negligible.

Comment: Thanks David. You're actually right. Adding the list is very fast compared to the rest of the work, and it does not make me lose the benefit of parallalization. It did when I simulated my "DoWork" with just a Console.WriteLine though. Thanks for your help.